# How to replace variables from file_get_contents() by their values in fwrite()?

Tags: php, forms, file-get-contents, fwrite

I have the large form and all data written by user are treated in a special way. My form after submitting should load template php file and add data from form into it. So my app treats POST data, loads the php template through `file_get_contents()` and throught `fwrite()` writes data into the new php file.

But here comes the problem. The variables, which were in the php template file, are written as they are. But I need to replace variables from php template by their values from submitted and parsed form POST header.

Does anybody know, how to do it?

My simplified code:

```
-- form.php
<Form Action="process.php" Method="post">
<Input Name="Name1" Type="text" Value="Value1">
<Button Type="submit">Submit</Button>

-- process.php
$Array=array(
"Name1","Name2",//...
);
if(!empty($_POST)){
foreach($Array as $Value){
if(!empty($_POST[$Value])){
$Value=$_POST[$Value];
}}}
...
$Template=file_get_contents("template.php");
$File=fopen("../export/".$userid.".html","w+");
fwrite($File,$Template);
fclose($File);

-- template.php
<!Doctype Html>
...
Name1: <?=$Name1?><Br>
...
```

My goal:

```
-- 135462.html
<!Doctype Html>
...
Name1: Value1
...
```

Comment: `fwrite()` does not parsing your PHP so all the code is just like plain text.

Comment: If the template is a PHP file, why don't you just `include` it instead ?

Comment: @barell Yes, I hadn't realized that (and I think, I'll do it in this way). But is there anything simpler and straighter?

Comment: @Niloct Because the template contains a lot of HTML

Comment: What ? Templates do have HTML, and mixed `<?php ?>` code. If you `include "template.phtml";` (for instance), all previous variables are immediately available to the template.

Comment: I don't understand the idea of include in my case. Could you add any little preview, ho to use `include "template.php";` together with `fwrite($newfile,$template);`?

Comment: You just don't `fwrite` back the new template, you output it directly. Why do you have to write the template with replaced values back in file ? Can you clarify with some code perhaps ?

Comment: Actually its an application form. User fills in the form and the file should be generated to download or print. The file is also stored on server (user has access by login). I'll try to simplify the code and write it into my question...

Comment: I added simplified code ↑

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for php buffers.
ob_* will help you do that.

Check http://php.net/ob_start

template.php :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body><?=$foo?></body>
</html>
```

index.php :

```
<?php
$foo = $_POST['text'];
ob_start();
include('template.php');
$template_html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

//do your stuff

echo $template_html;
?>
```

Comment: @AlesKvapil If you really need to write to file, change the last line of this answer to `fwrite($newfile,$template_html)` instead.

Comment: fwrite() or file_put_contents()

Comment: I use fwrite() and then also mail(). I tried it and works perfectly! Thanks you all.